# How to find empty directory using MobaXTerm portable version

Tags: linux, unix, busybox

I have read many many topics said just just the code below

```
find . -type d -empty
```

But it's shows he message below on my MobaXterm portable, BusyBox
I have read this article but don't know how to do that.

I'm also checked the MobaXTerm plugins, but still don't know how to use them on the MobaXTerm portable version.

```
    find /drives/d/ -type d -empty
find: unrecognized: -empty
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-09-26 07:33:17 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: find [-HL] [PATH]... [OPTIONS] [ACTIONS]

Search for files and perform actions on them.
First failed action stops processing of current file.
Defaults: PATH is current directory, action is '-print'

        -L,-follow      Follow symlinks
        -H              ...on command line only
        -xdev           Don't descend directories on other filesystems
        -maxdepth N     Descend at most N levels. -maxdepth 0 applies
                        actions to command line arguments only
        -mindepth N     Don't act on first N levels
        -depth          Act on directory *after* traversing it

Actions:
        ( ACTIONS )     Group actions for -o / -a
        ! ACT           Invert ACT's success/failure
        ACT1 [-a] ACT2  If ACT1 fails, stop, else do ACT2
        ACT1 -o ACT2    If ACT1 succeeds, stop, else do ACT2
                        Note: -a has higher priority than -o
        -name PATTERN   Match file name (w/o directory name) to PATTERN
        -iname PATTERN  Case insensitive -name
        -path PATTERN   Match path to PATTERN
        -ipath PATTERN  Case insensitive -path
        -regex PATTERN  Match path to regex PATTERN
        -type X         File type is X (one of: f,d,l,b,c,...)
        -perm MASK      At least one mask bit (+MASK), all bits (-MASK),
                        or exactly MASK bits are set in file's mode
        -mtime DAYS     mtime is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
                        or exactly N days in the past
        -mmin MINS      mtime is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
                        or exactly N minutes in the past
        -newer FILE     mtime is more recent than FILE's
        -inum N         File has inode number N
        -user NAME/ID   File is owned by given user
        -group NAME/ID  File is owned by given group
        -size N[bck]    File size is N (c:bytes,k:kbytes,b:512 bytes(def.))
                        +/-N: file size is bigger/smaller than N
        -links N        Number of links is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
                        or exactly N
        -prune          If current file is directory, don't descend into it
If none of the following actions is specified, -print is assumed
        -print          Print file name
        -print0         Print file name, NUL terminated
        -exec CMD ARG ; Run CMD with all instances of {} replaced by
                        file name. Fails if CMD exits with nonzero
        -delete         Delete current file/directory. Turns on -depth option
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using find from busy-box which is known for having issues for several options.

Although the help states that they are available.

I would suggest to use `find` from `findutils` [GNU package](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) if possible.

Comment: Thank you sir, But i have to use the BusyBox. Need to try installing additional package may be.

Comment: findutils fixed the issue for me